# not able to record

Tags: iphone, avaudiorecorder

I have created one test application for iPhone. I wrote the following code to record. But it is not working.

```
-(IBAction)start:(id)sender{
    recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    soundsDirectoryPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sounds"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Test.caf", soundsDirectoryPath] contents:nil attributes:nil];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Test.caf", soundsDirectoryPath]];
    NSError *err = nil;
    if([recorder isRecording])
    {
        [recorder stop];
        recorder = nil;
    }
    recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:&err];
    [recorder setDelegate:self];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    if(err){
        NSLog(@"Error : %@", [err description]);
    }
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    BOOL audioHWAvailable = audioSession.inputIsAvailable;
    if (! audioHWAvailable) {
        UIAlertView *cantRecordAlert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                   message: @"Audio input hardware not available"
                                  delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [cantRecordAlert show];
        [cantRecordAlert release]; 
        return;
    }
    BOOL st = [recorder prepareToRecord];
    if(!st){
        NSLog(@"Failed");
    }
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    BOOL status = [recorder record];
    if(!status)
    NSLog(@"Failed");
}

-(IBAction)stop:(id)sender{
    if([recorder isRecording]){
        NSLog(@"Recording...");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Not recording...");
    }
    [recorder stop];
}
```

When I call "start" method, it is printing "Failed" after calling "prepareToRecord", and "record" methods.

When I call "stop" method, it is printing "Not recording..." message.

what mistake I have made in this code.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a start button? You should also put a log in the start IBAction to make sure that it is even entering it.

Comment: I have a start button. When I click on start button, it is calling start method. If I use .m4a for .caf, it is giving some error;

Comment: This is test application. In my main application, it is working fine.

Comment: The `prepareToRecord` and `record` methods of AVAudioRecorder both return a boolean value, indicating their success or failure. Could you log those values and post them here? It will help to determine if recording begins and then fails, or if it never starts at all.

Comment: Which is giving a NO value, `record` or `prepareToRecord` (or both)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the extra information you provided in the question comments, it appears that there is a problem when creating the file associated with the recorder. This is indicated by the `NO` value returned by the `prepareToRecord` method.

One thing to note is that `prepareToRecord` creates the recording file on its own, using the URL supplied in the `init` method of AVAudioRecorder. There is no need to explicitly create it, as you do using NSFileManager.

Try logging the `soundsDirectoryPath`, and ensure that it's a valid file path.

EDIT: Found the real problem. You need to create the directory before the file is created. Replace this line:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Test.caf", soundsDirectoryPath] contents:nil attributes:nil];
```

With this one:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:soundsDirectoryPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL];
```

The new line only creates the directory and not the file, but that's fine because the `prepareToRecord` method creates the file automatically.

Comment: Path: "file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/97672452-4E3E-4131-ADF5-EDE4E154754F/Documents/Sounds" for soundDirectoryPath

Comment: It is working fine. After recording, if following statement executes, app is crashing with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" message. statement: NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Test.caf", soundsDirectoryPath]];

Comment: The `stringByAppendingPathComponent` method that you used to assign a value to `soundsDirectoryPath` doesn't retain its return value, so the string is autoreleased (and in this case `dealloc`'ed) at the end of the `start` method. Call `[soundsDirectoryPath retain]` before the `start` method finishes, but don't forget to `release` it when you no longer need it.